# С чего начать изучение HTML5?

Tags: html5

Подскажите, с чего начать изучение html 5. И вообще, насколько он отличается от простого html?

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 2):

- Поставить современный обозреватель ([Хром](http://www.google.ru/chrome)), чтобы было на чем работать с HTML5.
- Посмотреть ролик ([The Wilderness Downtown](http://www.thewildernessdowntown.com/)), чтобы прочувствовать возможности.
- Посмотреть слайды, примеры и руководства на ([HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/)), чтобы ознакомиться с деталями.
- Читать стандарт ([HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)), чтобы знать все.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала надо выучить HTML 4, но если по делу, то советую книгу "Изучаем HTML 5".

Answer (score 0):

Это, конечно, дело вкуса, но я бы начал с изучения [спецификации](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html).

> насколько он отличается от простого html?

Если под «простым» понимать HTML 4.01 / XHTML 1.1, то на этот счет тоже есть [документик](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/).